# UITableView becomes Nil After getting response from server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

This is my scenario,
    I have ViewController1 and Class1(Service Class).

I am loading tableView in nib by setting delegate and datasource in ViewController1. In viewDidLoad, i am calling a networkCall function in another class(Class1). In Class1, After getting a response it will pass an array of response data to a function in ViewController1 where the data should be populated in tableview.

i have connected datasource and delegate in xib.
Problem:
When i get a response as an array in ViewController1, UITableView becomes nil, i cannot able to use reloadData, but my array contains list of items from server.

Here's my code

ViewController1

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ClassA *class = [[ClassA alloc]init];
    [class getResponse];

}

//This method is calling from ClassA using delegate
-(void)responseData:(NSArray*)arrayList
{
//arrayList have response data
[tableView reloadData];//here tableView becomes nil.
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"array count %d",array.count);//has number of items(for me, its 3).
    return array.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableView";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = @"dsds";

    return cell;
}
```

tableView is calling first time.

In ViewController1
in interface, i am setting protocols

```
<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

Comment: in `(void)responseData` method try to `yourTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init]; [yourTableView reloadData];`

Comment: You don't seem to be setting your view controller as delegate for `ClassA * class` in your `- (void)viewDidLoad`. How exactly are you calling `-(void)responseData:(NSArray*)arrayList` from `ClassA`?

Comment: @Vladimir:
id<ViewController1Protocol>view1 = [[ViewController1 alloc]init];
     [view1 responseData:objects];
this is what i a calling

Comment: @RomanHouse: i tried with alloc init, but reloadData not calling delegate methods

Comment: @Anish yeah, that's what I thought. You are creating new instance (which never loads) instead of using the one that is displayed. I'll write an answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new instance of `ViewController1` instead of using the one that has been loaded.

you can do the following:

for ClassA:

interface:

```
@interface ClassA : ...
    @property (weak) ViewController1 * vcDelegate; 
...
@end
```

implementation:

```
@implementation ClassA
    @synthesize vcDelegate;
...
@end
```

and instead of

```
  id<ViewController1Protocol>view1 = [[ViewController1 alloc]init]; 
  [view1 responseData:objects];
```

call

```
  [vcDelegate responseData:objects];
```

In your ViewController, when creating `ClassA` you need to set delegate to self:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      ClassA *class = [[ClassA alloc]init];

      [class setVcDelegate: self];

      [class getResponse];          
 }
```

It's not the best implementation, but should give you idea of how to do it.

For example, property should probably be

```
@property (weak) id<ViewController1Protocol> vcDelegate;
```

Comment: it's working like a charm. i forgot to think of new alloc will create new instance //  id<ViewController1Protocol>view1 = [[ViewController1 alloc]init];Thanks for ur answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your `tableView` with the table view in the xib.

The red region in the image is not connected with your table view. It is empty.

[image]

Comment: i have connected with xib. the problem is when i load a viewcontroller1, tableview delegate methods are calling. but when i get a response from a server in responseData function, tableView becomes nil, i cannot able to use reloadData.

Comment: @Anish you have connected datasource and delegate properly and that's why these methods are being called. you have to connect the `IBOutlet` with referencing outlet in xib

Comment: but after getting a response from a server, tableview becomes nil <x0000000>. this is what i saw. so when i use reloadData, the tableView is not getting called.

Comment: if you check your `tableview` in viewDidLoad it will also show you nil. you can try it

Comment: yeah, it becomes nil. but i don't know the reason why i becomes nil.

Comment: the reason behind this is that you haven't bind your xib table view with the code variable. For that you create an `IBOutlet` and connect it. I have updated my answer.

Comment: but why should i connect Reference outlet connections, i am connecting New Reference Outlet with a tableVIew.i am declaring as IBOutlet tableView in .h,it working fine on first time

Comment: Sorry changed my image. Are you sure you are connected it properly ??

Comment: I dont know how you are calling your delegate method.Could you provide some code ???